# Why am I getting a "bad window path name" error when trying to add a label widget to the screen in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a homework planner program using Tkinter, and I've run into a problem when trying to add an error label to the screen to show the user that they might have entered a duplicate assignment. Here's the constructor for the label (entFrame is where I put the user entries):

```
duplicateLabel = Label(entFrame, text="Warning: the entered assignment is a duplicate!", bg=bgColor, font=regularFont)
```

When a user submits an assignment, a function runs that creates a new assignment object. In that function, I call a method of the assignment to check if it is a duplicate. In that method, I create a list of all the lines of a csv file where I store the assignments. Then, I check the new assignment's attributes to some of the stored attributes of previous assignments. If the conditional is true, I add the warning label to the screen. Otherwise, I try to destroy the label to remove it from the screen to get rid of a previous warning from an old assignment.

```
    def checkDuplicates(self):
        contents = []
        file = open("homeworkAssets/assignmentsFile", "r")
        for content in csv.reader(file):
            contents.append(content)
        file.close()
        for assignment in contents:
            if self.course == assignment[1] and self.dueDate == assignment[2] and self.details == assignment[3]:
                duplicateLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
            else:
                duplicateLabel.destroy()
```

My first thought was that the .destroy() method was deleting the Label object, although when I added a print statement after that last line, the console read: `.!labelframe.!labelframe.!label6` which I assume means it hasn't been deleted. When I run the program with an empty csv file and I add one assignment, and then a duplicate assignment, I receive this error message (sorry for the bad formatting, I couldn't figure out how to do it properly):

`File "/Users/max/Desktop/Coding/Python/Misc./homeworkPlannerRevised.py", line 212, in checkDuplicates duplicateLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2493, in grid_configure self.tk.call( _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!labelframe.!labelframe.!label6"`

Why is this error occurring and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of removing the label from the screen, simply clear and remove the text from the label using duplicateLabel['text'] = "".

Comment: @СергейКох     That sort of solves the problem, but the space is still taken up on screen by the empty label. Thank you!

Comment: you run it in loop - so in one loop it could deleted this label and in next loop it may try to delete it again - and this can make problem because label doesn't exist. After deleting you could set `duplicateLabel = None` and before deleting check `if duplicateLabel is not None:`

Comment: btw: shorter `contents = list(csv.reader(file))`

Comment: you can also use `grid_forget` to hide label without destroying it. And next you can use `grid` to show it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.destroy()` removes widget from window (and memory) but it  doesn't remove path from variable.
`print(duplicateLabel)` shows path to object even if it is destroyed.

You run `destroy()` in loop - so one loop can destroy label and next loop may try to destroy it again - and this can make problem.

You could assign `None` to variable after destroying and check `None` before destroying.

```
if duplicateLabel is not None:
    duplicateLabel.destroy()
    duplicateLabel = None
```

but if you destroy object then later you have to create it again

```
if duplicateLabel is None:
   duplicateLabel = Label(...)
```

But frankly you don't need `destroy()` but `grid_forget()` to hide widget without destroying.

```
if self.course == assignment[1] and self.dueDate == assignment[2] and self.details == assignment[3]:
    duplicateLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
else:
    duplicateLabel.grid_forget()
```